# Rails, Postgres display items present in all search params only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm looking to grab only records of sales if they exist in a shop between certain years. How best would I implement this search?

For example, a user selects the start year of 2013 and end year of 2016 and the shop name. The shop selected sold bananas and apples, but the shop only sold apples in 2013, 2014 and 2016. I want my results to only show the banana average sales as the apple wasn't sold in 2015.

So far I have the following query:

```
@sale_averages = Sale.joins(:shops, :items).where('extract(year from season_year) < ? AND extract(year from season_year) > ? ', params[:start_year], params[:end_year])
.where('shops.name = ?', params[:select_shop])
.select('items.name, AVG(sale.price) as price').group('shop.name')
```

Just unsure on how to create a query that filters out only items (or ids) that feature in all of the search params (years and shops).

**Schema**

```
create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string "name"
end

create_table "sales", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.integer "shop_id"
 t.integer "item_id"
 t.date "season_year"
 t.decimal "price"
end

create_table "shops", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string "name"
end
```

Comment: Sorry Ana. No difference. I shall remove this once the bounty is up as I have accepted your answer on the other one. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

I have no postgres installation here so it may need some correction, but the basic idea (at least my basic idea) here is to generate a list of years, select all items which are in one of the years, and then compare the count:

```
WITH years AS (
  SELECT * FROM generate_series(start_year,end_year);
)

SELECT  years, COUNT(items.id) AS item_count 
WHERE items.season_year IN years GROUP_BY(item.id)
HAVING COUNT(years) = item_count
```

Comment: Thanks Doctor, I've added my schema above. season_year is only present in sales, so I can't call items.season_year.

Comment: My answer is also only a demostration of a possible way to a solution. It of course may need another join, but the important part is: 1. Generate a series, 2. Select all items sold during this series, 3. Compare the size of the series and the list of items.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, I would be glad to learn why so I can learn something. The answer is way older than the duplicate question. The answer uses the same principle as the accepted answer there. It does not supply ready to go code which is however perfectly acceptable for this site. And it was the first answer to the question and gives away enough for the op to solve the rest by himself.